# Kivy on raspberry pi 3 error: No module named window x11

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am running the latest Raspbian Jessie image for raspberry pi 3 and attempting to run a kivy application and i am unable to fix this error i am getting.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /root/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-04-06_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:48:22) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider at all!
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name bcm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: No available video device
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 237, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 80, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1810)
  File "_window_sdl2.pyx", line 55, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1460)

x11 - ImportError: No module named window_x11
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
```

Comment: The actual error is sdl2's inability to find a video device. The x11 error is from an attempt to try an alternative window provider that isn't there because it hasn't been compiled (but nor is it supposed to be, so that's fine).

Comment: Why can't it find a video device? I have it connected to 4DPI-24-HAT touch screen. Also what about the egl_rpi error?

Comment: The egl_rpi thing normally just means that you're compiled with sdl2, not targeting the rpi specific backend. If you're using X11, it shouldn't matter as far as actually running goes.

Answer (score 1):

It took me about 2 hours of trying different things but I eventually figured out it requires a dependency that wasn't installed or listed as required for some reason: `pygame`. Simply run `pip3 install pygame`. Then try running your code again and it should magically work. This worked for me on Lubuntu 18.04 VM on my MacBook Pro.